# Handling temporary creation of foreign key table values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

I have a foreign table in my context called relationships each case can have many relationships. However I don't want to hit the final save until they have saved their full relationship until they finish there data entry but I still need a reference to it.

I am on here

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,RelationShipType")] RelationShips relationShips)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        var caseId = Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("CaseId"), out int resultcaseId);
        relationShips.RelationShipType = relationShips.RelationShipType;
        relationShips.isAcitve = true;
        relationShips.MisObjectId = resultcaseId;
        _context.Add(relationShips);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Relationships", new { Id = relationShips.Id });
}
```

Obv I could just remove the line

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and pass in the relationship object as such

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Relationships", new { Id = relationShips.Id }, res);
```

But is that the correct way of handling it I have relationship setup as a one to many to my case

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RelationShips>()
   .HasOne<MISObject>(s => s.Case)
   .WithMany(g => g.RelationShip)
   .HasForeignKey(s => s.MisObjectId);
```

Or should I be doing.

```
_context.MSIobject.Relationships.Add
```

The only thing is

Even if i have it here in my `DbContext` I can't seem to access from MSIobject

```
public DbSet<RelationShips> RelationShips { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not quite clear. Why could you *obviously* remove `SaveChangesAsync`? That would mean the method does nothing, unless `_context` is static, which I sincerely hope it's not. And what about a useless statement ike `relationShips.RelationShipType = relationShips.RelationShipType`, and not using `caseId`, and `_context.MSIobject` probably being a `DbSet`, not having a `Relationships` property? It all looks pretty tentative.

Comment: @GertArnold I think i need like a tempory table to hold the link between relationalship and the case until the person hits save.

Comment: You would typically build the objects in memory on the client and only send them to the server when you're ready to save them, or accumulate them in session state until you run a Save API.  IE use either the client memory or server session state instead of a temporary table.